# Range.ArrayFormula causing error in specific cases

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range, formula

I have a piece of code which puts an array formula in a range. It is throwing

> runtime error:438 "Object doesn't support this property or method"

But when I paste the same formula in the cell and hit `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

everything works fine.

```
strFormula = "=IF(SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423))=0,TEXT(,),SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423)))"

shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").ArrayFormula  = strFormula
```

The problem occurs when the `IF` condition was inserted. So without the `IF` the following code works fine:

```
strFormula = "=SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423))"

shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").ArrayFormula = strFormula
```

**NOTE:** If I use `shtAbsoluteData.Range("D2").Formula` then there is no error but the result is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can't enter strings with a length of more than 255 characters directly via vba as like in your case. Please use the [Replace](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/)-trick for such cases.

Answer (score 0):

The code shall probably read:

```
strFormula = "=IF(SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423))=0, """" ,SUM(--(A2=Data!$A$2:$A$1423)*--(B2=YEAR(Data!$B$2:$B$1423))*  --(C2=MONTH(Data!$B$2:$B$1423)) * (Data!$E$2:$E$1423)))"
```

it should help if it is **Text** with empty arguments what makes problem.

PS. Note doubled quotation marks